# Rendering XML with inline styles WITH OTHER FILE EXTENSION works in Firefox, but not Chrome. How to let chrome render XML with other file extension?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, render, local

I have been working on rendering local XML with local XSLT. I solved the problem (with help of googling) by using inline style sheet. So my xml is beautifully rendered by Firefox and Chrome.

But If I change the file extension from .xml to something else like .aml, Firefox still renders the file, but Chrome not any more. Chrome just give out the file content in plain text within  tag.

My question is, how to let Chrome render local xml file with other entensions?

Here is my file content (this code was found on the internet, not from me, just as an example):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
 <!--Start XSL-->
 <xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />

   <!--Variables-->
   <xsl:variable name="a" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='Yes']" />
   <xsl:variable name="b" select="/doc/list/movie/seen" />
   <xsl:variable name="c" select="sum(/doc/list/movie/rating/@value)" />
   <xsl:variable name="d" select="$c div count($a)" />
   <xsl:variable name="e" select="count($a) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="f" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='No']" />
   <xsl:variable name="g" select="/doc/list/movie/seen[@value ='Prior']" />
   <xsl:variable name="h" select="count($f) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="j" select="count($g) div count($b)" />
   <xsl:variable name="minutes_total" select="sum(/doc/list/movie/length[@value ='y'])" />
   <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="$minutes_total mod 60" />
   <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($minutes_total div 60) mod 24" />
   <xsl:variable name="hours2" select="floor($minutes_total div 60)" />
   <xsl:variable name="days" select="floor($hours2 div 24)" />
   <!--End Variables-->

  <xsl:decimal-format name="percent" />
  <xsl:decimal-format name="average" decimal-separator="." />

  <xsl:template match="/doc">
   <html>
    <head>
     <style>
      h2{
      font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;
      font-size: 32px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      }
      body{
      font-family: Courier New, monospace;
      }
      p{
      font-size: 16px;
      }
      table{
      font-size: 14px;
      }
      .title{
      text-align:left;
      }
      .release{
      text-align:center;
      }
      .seen{
      text-align:center;
      }
      .rating{
      text-align:right;
      }
      .length{
      text-align:center;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h2>My Movie List</h2>
     <p>Movies seen so far: <xsl:value-of select="count($a)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($e, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Movies yet to see: <xsl:value-of select="count($f)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Movies seen prior to making list: <xsl:value-of select="count($g)" />/<xsl:value-of select="count($b)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="format-number($j, '#%', 'percent')" /><br />
     Total time watched: <xsl:value-of select="format-number($days, '#0')" /> days, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($hours, '#0')" /> hours, <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes, '#0')" /> minutes<br />
     Average rating:  <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '#.000', 'average')" /> stars out of 5</p>
     <br />
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Release Date</th>
       <th>Length</th>
       <th>Seen</th>
       <th>Rating</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="list/movie">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='seen = "Yes"'>
         <tr style="background-color:#666; color:#fff">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test='seen = "Seen prior to making list"'>
         <tr style="background-color:#999; color:#000">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length"/> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
          <td> <xsl:number /></td>
          <td class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="release"><xsl:value-of select="release"/></td>
          <td class="length"><xsl:value-of select="length" /> minutes</td>
          <td class="seen"><xsl:value-of select="seen"/></td>
          <td class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>

 <!--Start XML-->
 <list>
  <movie>
   <title>2001: A Space Odyssey</title>
   <release>1968</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">141</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>28 Days Later</title>
   <release>2002</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">113</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>28 Weeks Later</title>
   <release>2007</release>
   <seen value="No">No</seen>
   <rating>N/A</rating>
   <length value="n">100</length>
  </movie>
  <movie>
   <title>A Clockwork Orange</title>
   <release>1971</release>
   <seen value="Yes">Yes</seen>
   <rating value="2">&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;&#9733;&#9733;</rating>
   <length value="y">136</length>
  </movie>
  <!--Rest of XML-->
 </list>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Chrome uses system-wide mime type database.

So regist e.g. ".aml" as "application/xml" will solve the problem.